# how do i subtract two grandtotal fields in Crystal Reports

Tags: syntax, crystal-reports, report, formula

I'm using crystal reports and i have created two sum grandtotal fields. Now i want to do field 1 - field 2 in a X1 formula, but i can't call those fields into the formula. So I tried to use Sum({field1}) - 2 but that doesn't seem to get the grandtotal.

Is it possible to do a grandtotal in a sum like Sum({field1}.GrandTotal) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a formula and write

```
Sum({field1}-Sum({field2}
```

and place it at the right most part that is after all columns.

If this doesn't work then you can follow below process.

---

Create a formula @Grandtotal1

```
Sum({field1},{Group1}(if using group)
```

create a formula @Grandtotal2

```
Sum({field1},{Group2}(if using group)
```

Now create another formula

```
EvaluateAfter(@Grandtotal1);
EvaluateAfter(@Grandtotal2)

@Grandtotal1-@Grandtotal2
```

Comment: Thanks! i got it now.